Is my Idea correct? About an electric field applied in a medium?
I think that, when the electric field is applied in a medium then, atoms of that medium become polarised. So, work is done to hold them like that, and energy of the electric field is consumed in this process.
This process continues until electrical energy becomes negligible.
There would be, a decrease in energy per unit distance. Is permittivity a measure of this negative energy gradient? Is this true ?

So do they have the same polarized orientation even after removing the field ?

Energy is never spent on keeping something in the same state, when no energy is lost to the surroundings

Some comments deleted. Please remember that comments are not for extended discussion; if you want to answer a question, write an answer.


So, work is done to hold them like that, and energy of the electric
field is consumed in this process.

Work is done by the electric field polarizing the medium, but no work is done to keep the medium polarized.
A spring analogy is work is required to twist (a torsion spring) or extend/compress a spring by a force . The force is required to maintain the spring, but no work as work is force times displacement.  When the force is removed, the spring  eventually returns to its natural state, the elastic potential energy acquired due to the work done by the external force converted to kinetic energy or dissipated as heat.
Hope this helps.

Yea thanks, i understand the confusion.
